# Dynamic SQL concatenate strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the SQL below:

```
declare @TableName VarChar(100)
declare @field1 varchar(100)
declare @field2 varchar(100)
set @TableName = 'Person.Person'
set @field1  = 'LastName'
set @field2  = 'FirstName'
Declare @SQL VarChar(1000) SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @field1 + ',' + @field2 + ' FROM '
 SELECT @SQL = @SQL + @TableName 
 Exec ( @SQL)
```

The result set appears in two columns i.e. firstname and surname.  Is it possible to concatenate the columns so the output appears like this?

```
Ian,McFearce
Jane,McAndrew
```

I have found a quote on this website: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx, which states:  "concatenating two strings with the + operator, are not allowed".  Therefore I suspect it is not possible.  Is there a workaround.

Comment: ur sql needs to be select lastname + ','+firstname  from person

Comment: Where does `@TableName` ultimately come from? Why is your system designed so that people can choose any columns from any table?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, the system searches a number of local databases, which have different schemas.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @TableName VarChar(100)
declare @field1 varchar(100)
declare @field2 varchar(100)
set @TableName = 'dbo.Person'
set @field1  = 'LastName'
set @field2  = 'FirstName'
Declare @SQL VarChar(1000) SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @field1 + '+'',''+' + @field2 + ' FROM '
 SELECT @SQL = @SQL + @TableName 
 print @sql
 Exec ( @SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for that +1.  Can you comment on the quote from the webstie i.e. " concatenating two strings with the + operator, are not allowed".

Comment: i guess it means, you can't have something like Exec(@SQL+@WhereClause). @stmt should be a unicode constant or unicode variable

Comment: Lastly, do you think this approach should be frowned upon because of SQL injection risks?

Comment: I would use `QUOTENAME()` around the column names to prevent SQL injection; also [`sp_executesql` is a much better pattern in general, especially if there are going to be proper parameters later](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx).